# Why does my listener get deleted when I saveobj()?

Tags: matlab, listener

Suppose I have two classes, `a < matlab.mixin.Copyable` and `b < handle`.

Here's `a`:

```
classdef a < matlab.mixin.Copyable
    properties
        hListener
    end

    methods
        function obj = a(b)
            obj.newListener(b);
        end

        function newListener(obj, b)
            obj.hListener = addlistener(b, 'bEvent', @(o,e) disp('Received bEvent'));
        end

        function sobj = saveobj(obj)
            sobj = copy(obj);

            delete(sobj.hListener);
            sobj.hListener = [];
        end

    end
end
```

and `b`:

```
classdef b < handle
    events
        bEvent
    end

    methods
        function obj = b

        end

        function raiseEvent(obj)
            notify(obj, 'bEvent');
        end
    end

end
```

I use `saveobj` in `a` to delete the listener upon save. I will manually re-instantiate a listener when I load the classes later.

`a` inherits from `matlab.mixin.Copyable` so I can do a `copy` during the `saveobj` operation - this way I can make a copy of the original object and change it, without affecting the original, and then save that to a MAT-file. (Supposedly - this is where my question is going.)

---

Now I run the following at the command line:

```
>> bob = b; alice = a(bob);
>> bob.raiseEvent
Received bEvent
```

Everything works. Now, let's save:

```
>> save ab alice bob
```

and try to raise the event again:

```
>> bob.raiseEvent
% NOTHING HAPPENS!
```

Turns out the listener is gone!

```
>> alice.hListener
handle to deleted listener
```

What is going on here? Why is the `listener` object shared between `sobj` and `obj` in the `saveobj` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In researching this question I discovered the answer. I figured I'd add to the body of knowledge around these parts.

Per the [documentation for `matlab.mixin.Copyable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.copyableclass.html),

> Given a call to the matlab.mixin.Copyable copy method of the form:
>
> `B = copy(A);`
>
> Under the following conditions, produces the described results:
>
> `A` has dynamic properties — `copy` does not copy dynamic properties. You can implement dynamic-property copying in the subclass if needed.
>
> `A` has no non-Dependent properties — `copy` creates a new object with no property values without calling the class constructor to avoid introducing side effects.
>
> `A` contains deleted handles — `copy` creates deleted handles of the same class in the output array.
>
> **`A` has attached listeners — `copy` does not copy listeners.** ***(emphasis added)***
>
> `A` contains objects of enumeration classes — Enumeration classes cannot subclass `matlab.mixin.Copyable`.
>
> `A` delete method calls `copy` — `copy` creates a legitimate copy, obeying all the behaviors that apply in any other usage.

What I took this to mean originally was that a `copy` call would skip over a property whose value is a listener handle. Apparently what it means is that rather than skipping the property altogether, `copy` makes a reference to the original `listener` object, i.e., it copies the handle to the listener but not the listener itself.

Of course, when you `load` the copied object and it has that reference to listener, it'll complain:

```
Warning: Cannot load an object of class 'listener':
 No matching constructor signature found. 
Warning: During load:
 An invalid default object has been detected while loading a heterogeneous array of
 class event.listener. An empty array of class event.listener will be returned.
```

The easiest thing to do, then, is to modify `saveobj`:

```
function sobj = saveobj(obj)
    sobj = copy(obj);
        
    sobj.hListener = [];
end
```

Here, I don't explicitly call `delete` on the listener, as this would delete the actual object. Instead, I just clear the reference to that object.